# Javascript/css external blocking rendering error

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pagespeed

I'm facing with a problem. I have a lot of external blocking rendering error as you can see from here: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=antsmarching.com.au&tab=desktop

I tried to do my best and I had some good outcome. In the beginning there were 44 errors, now "just" 19. The problem is that in the header.php I cannot see any of this resources... Can you help me to do a little better?

thanks,
Daniele

Answer (score 0):

Use GTMetrix, which gives you a better idea of what's important to work on in terms of site speed: http://gtmetrix.com/reports/antsmarching.com.au/cUDaZCu4  i.e., optimize images, specify image dimensions, avoid CSS @import, remove query strings from static resources. You can mostly forget "blocking javascripts"; that's really not a issue.

And be sure you have a good webhost, too. But you already have a low A, so that's good.

And see https://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Optimization/WordPress_Performance

Comment: Don't post the same question twice; I put a close vote on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29909078/javascript-css-external-blocking-rendering-error

Answer (score 0):

I did a webpage test of your site `http://www.antsmarching.com.au/`. You can find the result [here](http://goo.gl/YC4ZRI) According to the result i suggest these steps

1. Use persistent connections(Keep alive) : Your current score is 28/100
   [image]

Too many orange bars refers to failure in usage of keep alive connections. Refer [this](http://www.feedthebot.com/pagespeed/keep-alive.html) for some ideas to fix this problem. [Screenshot](http://cl.ly/anTH/1_optimization.png) give you current  keep alive failures

2. Enable gzip for *.ttf files. You can save 22.3KB
3. Compress Images: Few images are yet to be compressed. You can save 37.5 KB
4. Leverage browser caching of static assets
5. Better to serve all static files from a sub domain where you can disable cookies and unnecessary overheads.